# <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'> decoding method

Tags: python, class, encoding

I am trying to read a content of a file:

```
    with open (os.path.join(root,file),"r",encoding='cp932') as content_file:
        continut=content_file.read()
        print(content_file)
```

But the problem is that the output is:

```
 1 4 0 6 0   |   2 3 . 0 7 . 2 2   0 5 : 0 4 : 2 4 . 3 5 9   | 2 |   < < < < =   O T X R T _ E x e c u t e O T X P r o j e c t ( < R e t u r n > = 6 5 0 9 )
```

Can someone help me with an explication why I have more spaces?
The content of original files that I want to read is:

```
14060 | 23.07.22 05:04:24.359 |2| <<<<= OTXRT_ExecuteOTXProject(<Return>=6509)
```

I search and seams to be the issue from with open (os.path.join(root,file)
I tried also with encoding "utf-8" but I encounter the nest issue:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0):

please use :
f = open(r'C:\Users\uic81314\Desktop\Test_Results\OtxRuntime.log',mode ="r",encoding="utf-16").read()
print (f)

as example